# How to use jQuery select / .change() to reveal a hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, user-interface

I have the following select field and based on whether the class `.show-x-trend` or `show-x` is selected I would like to conditionally reveal a separate div.  If `.show-x-trend` `<option>` is selected, I'd like to reveal the already hidden `#x-axis-trend-wrap` `<div>` and if  `show-x` option is selected I'd like to reveal the already hidden `#x-axis-wrap` `<div>`.  In the code below, you'll see that I have both CSS classes and also values assigned to the 3 selection options because I tried to achieve the effect a few different ways but so far with no luck.

```
<div id="visualize-wrap">
    <h3>Visualization Shows</h3>
    <select id="visualize-shows" name="visualize">
        <option class="no-show" value="00">Select One</option>
        <option class="show-x-trend" value="01">Trend Over Time</option>
        <option class="show-x" value="02">Breakdown of Sum Total</option>
        <option class="show-x" value="03">Side-by-side Comparison</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't get it. Can you be a bit more clear? You want to select an option and hide/show a div depending on the option's class? Is that it?

Comment: @elclanrs thats exactly how i read it !

Comment: @elclanrs that's right.  If `option.show-x-trend` is selected, I fade in `div#x-axis-trend-wrap`.  `option.show-x` is selected, I fade in `div#x-axis-wrap`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `hasClass` method to determine if the selected option contains the required class or not and act accordingly.

```
$('#visualize-shows').change(function(){
    var $selectedOption = $(this).find('option:selected');
    $('#x-axis-trend-wrap')
    .toggle( $selectedOption.hasClass('show-x-trend'));
    $('#x-axis-wrap')
    .toggle( $selectedOption.hasClass('show-x'));
});
```

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/X2dPt/

Comment: +1 nice ... didnt know `.toggle()` could be passed a boolean ... simpler than mine !!! Always learning with jQuery

Comment: console is telling me that `object has no method "option"`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
$("#visualize-shows").change(function() {
   $selected = $(this).find('option:selected'); // get selected option
   if ($selected.hasClass('show-x-trend')) { // check the class
      $('#x-axis-trend-wrap').toggle(); // toggle display
   } else if ($selected.hasClass('show-x')) {
      $('#x-axis-wrap').toggle();
   }
});
```

this uses [.hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

Comment: Please correct this `$(this).option(':selected')`, it should be `find` instead of option :)